# Appending a list in a list using a for loop

Tags: r

I'm a beginner in R and I'm facing a rather simple issue. I need to create a list of a list iteratively with the data that is given below.

```
# First Vertical layer
P01<- list("S17","S18")
P02<- list("S1","S2")
P03<- list("S3","S4")

P1 <- list(P01, P02, P03)
# Second Vertical layer
P2 <- list("S22","S11","S12")
```

For each list in P1, I need to append it to the start of each value in P2 and record it in a list. What I need:

```
lt <- list(list("S17", "S18", "S22"),list("S17", "S18", "S11"),list("S17", "S18", "S12"), list("S1", "S2", "S22"), ....)
```

What I have written so far (but doesn't work):

```
for (val in P1){
  for (lev in P2){
    J <- append(val,lev)
  }
}
```

I'm coming from a python background and this syntax and data type is becoming a bit problematic for me in R. Any help would be sufficient.

Comment: If order does not matter, a simple approach is: `purrr::cross2(P1,P2) %>% map(unlist, recursive = FALSE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the order does not matter you can use `expand.grid` and than `unlist` the result in `lapply`:

```
x <- lapply(asplit(expand.grid(P1, P2), 1), function(x) as.list(unlist(x)))
x[1:2]
#[[1]]
#[[1]]$Var11
#[1] "S17"
#
#[[1]]$Var12
#[1] "S18"
#
#[[1]]$Var2
#[1] "S22"
#
#
#[[2]]
#[[2]]$Var11
#[1] "S1"
#
#[[2]]$Var12
#[1] "S2"
#
#[[2]]$Var2
#[1] "S22"
```

And in case order matters:

```
x <- lapply(asplit(rev(expand.grid(P2, P1)), 1), function(x) as.list(unlist(x)))
x[1:2]
#[[1]]
#[[1]]$Var21
#[1] "S17"
#
#[[1]]$Var22
#[1] "S18"
#
#[[1]]$Var1
#[1] "S22"
#
#
#[[2]]
#[[2]]$Var21
#[1] "S17"
#
#[[2]]$Var22
#[1] "S18"
#
#[[2]]$Var1
#[1] "S11"
```

Comment: This works too but unfortunately the order does matter because this is a production line.

Comment: Very creative, congratulations, I would have never remind myself of `asplit(., 1)`.

Answer (score 2):

A one-liner base R solution.

```
lapply(P1, function(x) lapply(P2, function(y) c(unlist(x), y)))
```

Comment: This does not give the solution OP wants. He wants all combinations. i.e. S17,S18,S22; S17,S18,S11 and so on

Comment: Exactly Ali, I need all the combinations.

Comment: @Ali Right, didn't notice that. Thanks, I will revise the answer.